# Unexpected token % in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**Code:**

```
$scope.username=JSON.parse(getCookie('authData')).Username;
```

This is what `getCookie('authData')` contains:

```
%7B%22UserID%22%3A%22c980b08240178f48a4607cd1d081664b%22%2C%22Username%22%3A%22sajeetharan%40duosoftware.com%22%2C%22Name%22%3A%22sajeetharan+sinnathurai%22%2C%22Email%22%3A%22sajeetharan%40duosoftware.com%22%2C%22SecurityToken%22%3A%22a7dd024d5158c7e1ee4807cb9716cc6f%22%2C%22Domain%22%3A%22sajeetharan.digin.io%22%2C%22DataCaps%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ClientIP%22%3A%22104.155.236.85%3A33776%22%2C%22Otherdata%22%3A%7B%22JWT%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkbW4iOiJzYWplZXRoYXJhbi5kaWdpbi5pbyIsImVtbCI6InNhamVldGhhcmFuQGR1b3NvZnR3YXJlLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6InNhamVldGhhcmFuLmRpZ2luLmlvIiwic2NvcGUiOnt9LCJzdCI6ImE3ZGQwMjRkNTE1OGM3ZTFlZTQ4MDdjYjk3MTZjYzZmIiwidWlkIjoiYzk4MGIwODI0MDE3OGY0OGE0NjA3Y2QxZDA4MTY2NGIifQ%3D%3D.YpFKYAw0t3RQkbrM9sjY1QAkz4AUxsmlE5uXMy%5C%2Fsc%3D%22%2C%22Scope%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Looks urlencoded to me. . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) `decodeURIComponent()`:

```
$scope.username=JSON.parse(
    decodeURIComponent(getCookie('authData'))
).Username
```

The cookie value is just encoded.

> Cookie values may not include semicolons, commas, or whitespace. For
>   this reason, you may want to use the JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()`
>   function to encode the value before storing it in the cookie. If you
>   do this, you will also have to use the corresponding
>   `decodeURIComponent()` function when you read the cookie value.

More details in [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm).